# What is the reason for this error in execution?

Tags: python, machine-learning

Hello I am new to python and machine learning , I cannot understand why this error is being posted. A few days ago this worked out fine. Can someone please explain this error and rectify it. thanks

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer=Imputer(missing_values ='NaN', strategy='mean', axis = 0)
```

This is the error which occurs:

> `DeprecationWarning: Class Imputer is deprecated; Imputer was deprecated in version 0.20 and will be removed in 0.22. Import impute.SimpleImputer from sklearn instead.
>     warnings.warn(msg, category=DeprecationWarning)`

Comment: My guess is you updated a package, or someone else did.  Now that feature is changed, and you need to import it as specified in the warning.  Use `from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer`

Comment: This is not an error. This is a warning which is suggesting that class Imputer is going to be removed in the future versions. If you want your code working with the future versions, replace that with the new package called `SimpleImputer`.

Comment: this is not an error, but a warning you should use it the way it is instructed in warning message.

Comment: See [sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html), there is no `axis` parameter. After importing the new package, use `imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values ='NaN', strategy='mean')`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because in the latest version of `sklearn` library `Imputer` has changed to `SimpleImputer`.
So, the solution to this is simply to replace `Imputer` with `SimpleImputer`

Answer (score 0):

use instead `sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer` because the old `Imputer` is deprecated.